# streamlit run file_name.py SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python-3.x, windows, pip, pycharm, streamlit

I am trying to execute a streamlit application and I get the following error:

**streamlit run file_name.py SyntaxError: invalid syntax**

I installed Streamlit using conda and pip and I still get the same error after verifying installation with "pip list" and "conda list" commands... please help

Answer (score 0):

These are some step  you can take:

**(1)** Navigate to the directory where your project is located with with the `cd` command.

**(2)** Activate your `venv` on terminal  with  `Scripts/activate`.

**(3)** You can then run `streamlit run file_name.py`.